# Use ports other than 80/443 for the event notification url (webhook)

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible to use other ports than 80(http) and 443(https) for the event notification url when setting up a webhook? Like this:

```
EventNotification eventNotification = new EventNotification();
eventNotification.Url = "http://example.com:82/Test.asmx/ReceivingMethod";
```

I can't tell if my server is blocking the traffic or if DocuSign can't use that url.

I am using [Docusign C# SDK.](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the service [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to create a public SSL 443 service point that is tunneled to your server's port 82.

### Updated Dec, 2018:

Currently, you can only use TLS v1.1 or greater in demo and production. You can also use other destination ports, but they must all use https. Ports supported: 443, 1443, 2443, 3443, 4443, 5443, 6443, 7443, 8443, or 9443

Answer (score 1):

You can use 80/443 in DEMO. You must use 443 in PROD.

Comment: This is no longer correct. You must use TLS v1.1 or greater in prod and demo (no port 80) and other ports can now be used. See my updated answer.