# Docusign Webhook Error: "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

Tags: apache, docusignapi, webhooks

I'm using the DocuSign API to set up a webhook listener for my envelope events. My webhook is an API endpoint that I have running on an AWS instance. I've tried both including the webhook on a per envelope basis and using the Connect feature. In both cases, the request isn't even reaching my Apache server.

Checking the failures I see the error

> "Unable to connect to the remote server; No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it".

I've made sure the endpoint isn't being blocked nor are external requests. I'm able to successfully make a POST request to the endpoint using Postman so I'm sure it's working.

My endpoint is running on port **8000**, so is it possible that DocuSign is ignoring that and trying to send it to port **80**?

I have set the URL as "http://MY_IP:8000/..." and I am running DocuSign in development mode so the lack of **SSL** should not be an issue.

Comment: Do you encounter this issue sometimes or at all times ?

Comment: I encounter this issue with every event.

Comment: I'd agree that the DS connect for HTTP should be using port 80.

Comment: The API that I have set up is running on port 8000. There's no way around that. There's no way to use that endpoint as a webhook?

Comment: DocuSign Demo allows 80/443 and Production only allows 443

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use ports other than 80/443 for the event notification url (webhook)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37294334/use-ports-other-than-80-443-for-the-event-notification-url-webhook)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My assumption proved to be correct, it turns out that Docusign only supports webhook listeners on either port 80 or 443. For anyone else experiencing this issue, I ended up using proxy_pass in my NGINX conf file which was running on port 80 to forward the request to my api on port 8000. More specifically:

```
location /< WEBHOOK> {
    proxy_pass http://< DOMAIN >:8000/< WEBHOOK >;
}
```

Hope this is helpful to anyone else with this issue!

Comment: To add to this, DocuSign Demo allows 80/443 and Production only allows 443